# How to map objects received from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a simple question which I can't find an answer to. I'm really new to Firebase and it seems that the way I fetch data is not the same which is used in the documentation and I have a hard time operating with that.

So basically I have 2 collections Transactions and Categories.
Where Transaction looks like this:
[image]

And I fetch this data into the flow list like this:

```
override val transactions: Flow<List<Transaction>>
        get() =
            auth.currentUser.flatMapLatest { user ->

                firestore.collection(TRANSACTIONS)
                    .whereEqualTo(USERID, user.id)
                    .dataObjects<Transaction>()
                    .flatMapLatest { transactions ->
                        categories.flatMapLatest { categories ->
                            flow {
                                emit(transactions.map { transaction ->
                                    transaction.copy(
                                        category = categories.find { 
                                            it.id == transaction.categoryId }
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

So the question is, is there any better way to map this Transaction object so it automatically receives Category but not just its id? Because currently I have 2 properties category and categoryId, which doesn't really makes sense, since Category class contains its id anyway.

I expect my Transaction class to have only category property

```
data class Transaction (
    @DocumentId val id: String = "",
    val amount: Double = 0.0,
    val type: TransactionType = TransactionType.INCOME,
    val date: String = "",
    val description: String= "",
    //val categoryId: String = "",
    val category: Category? = null,
    val userId: String = "",
)
```

Comment: From where you are getting `categories` list. Did you fetch them all before fetching `transactions` ?